# Start to start dependency with lag less than zero

Tags: project-management

Suppose you have two tasks A and B both of 1 day duration (they start the same day). I set start-to-start dependency on them, which means that task B can't start until task A starts.

Then I set the lag to -1. Now task B starts before task A.

Can someone please explain it to me? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: Not programming related, at least not the way the question is phrased.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming.

Answer (score 2):

You started out saying that B can't start until A starts.  What you've actually said is that B can't start until (at the earliest) 0 days after A starts.

Ok, now change the number to -1.  There are many ways to read it...

B can't start until (at the earliest) -1 days after A starts.
B can't start until (at the earliest) 1 day before A starts.
A can't start any later than 1 day after B starts.
A must start within 1 day of B starting.

Answer (score 1):

Rob F explained it quite nicely, but let me put this into an example:

Imagine you're doing [alfresco](http://www.fauxfinish.com/FauxFinish/faux-fresco.htm) decoration.

You are decorating a wall, which needs to be plastered (B) and painted (A). However, you can only paint in semi-dried (half-wet) plaster. Hence, you must start plastering before decorating, but not too long before it, because then it will have dried too much. It's delicate timing.